# PingAccess does not preserve contextroot following authentication

Tags: pingaccess

My webapp (in my enterprise) previously used a PING agent on team-level Apache to prompt for authentication.  Following authentication, the connection would then be redirected to a backend URL hosted by a WAS running the webapp.

We want to change to use an enterprise-level

Example:

https://mysite.host.com/ApplicationContextRoot pointed to a team-level Apache with a PING agent, and following Authentication forwarded to https://backend.host.com/ApplicationContextRoot

We want to switch to:

https://mysite.host.com/ApplicationContextRoot points to enterprise-level PingAccess box and following authentication forward to https://backend.host.com/ApplicationContextRoot, thus removing the team-level Apache and PING agent from my buildout.

My problem is that when the enterprise level tech configured our PingAccess virtual host, it strips the ApplicationContextRoot when forwarding to the backend.

In short:

https://mysite.host.com/ApplicationContextRoot prompts for Authentication and then forwards to https://backend.host.com/  <-- note no context root.

Please note that I'm not the actual person doing the configuration or the person with direct access to the Configuration, so I'm not familiar with how to configure it beyond what our tech showed me in a shared screen. I'm looking for "what I need to tell the GUY WHO DOES what to do to get me working".

Thanks,

-Gordon